# Vue - troubles creating form using v-for

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, v-for

I'm trying to make form using v-for, however I bumped into a problem when trying to do it for fields that have input rules assigned. Working code looks like this (this example is password):

```
<v-col cols="5">
<v-text-field
        label="Password"
            type="password"
            v-model="password"
            :rules="[
                rules.required,
                rules.counter(password, 16),
                rules.regex(password),
            ]"
></v-text-field>
<v-col cols="5">
<v-text-field
        label="Type password again"
            type="password"
            v-model="password2"
            :rules="[
                rules.required,
                rules.matching(password, password2)
            ]"
></v-text-field>
```

Then my modified code is like below:

```
    <v-col 
    cols="5"
    v-for="(field, i) in fields"
    :key="i">
    <v-text-field
    :label="field.label"
        :type="field.type"
        :v-model="field.model"
        :rules="field.rules"
></v-text-field>
</v-col>
```

in script part:

```
fields: [
    { label: 'Password', type: 'password', model: 'password', rules: '[rules.required, rules.counter(password, 16), rules.regex(password)]' },
    { label: 'Type password again', type: 'password', model: 'password2', rules: '[rules.required, rules.matching(password, password2)]' },
  ],
```

The label and inside of the box looks fine but when I try to type something into it, the rules are not working properly (instead of normal information like 'You need to use at least 16 characters' I get only '[' under the box).

The same things happens when I try to do comboboxes using v-for: labels work OK, but it's not loading lists as options anymore.
What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for any replies!

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is caused by the fact that the model fields need to be variables, and not literal strings, something along the lines of this:

```js
password: "",
passwordConfirmation: "",
fields: [
    { label: 'Password', type: 'password', model: password, rules: '[rules.required, rules.counter(password, 16), rules.regex(password)]' },
    { label: 'Type password again', type: 'password', model: passwordConfirmation, rules: '[rules.required, rules.matching(password, passwordConfirmation)]' },
  ],
```

If this does not resolve your problem, please provide more code than just a few select snippets.